# Why is my function factory not working?

Tags: javascript

I am curious as to why this function does not work. I've noticed that it is returning undefined instead of an anonymous function object as I would expect.

```
function localizeGreeting(language) {
    (function(lang) {        
        if (lang === 'en') {
            return function(firstname, lastname) { 
                console.log('Hello' + firstname + ' ' + lastname);
            }
        }

        if (lang === 'es') {
            return function(firstname, lastname) { 
                console.log('Hola' + firstname + ' ' + lastname);
            }
        }
    })(language);
}

var test = localizeGreeting('en');
test('Dave', 'Matthews');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your outer function doesn't return anything.

It calls an inner function that returns a value, but it then ignores that return value.

*Side note*: There is no reason to have the intermediary IIFE in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

This is not the correct approach. You do not need an IIFE out here. The below solution would work

```
function localizeGreeting(lang) {        
    if (lang === 'en') {
        return function(firstname, lastname) { 
            console.log('Hello' + firstname + ' ' + lastname);
        }
    }

    if (lang === 'es') {
        return function(firstname, lastname) { 
            console.log('Hola' + firstname + ' ' + lastname);
        }
    }
}

var test = localizeGreeting('en');
test('Dave', 'Matthews');
```